# How to get and pass user conversation data to backend API in Azure Bot Framework Composer v1.4.0?

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, chatbot

I am new to **Azure Bot Framework Composer**.

I am creating chatbot using **Azure Bot Framework Composer**(without writing code) which need to be launch in Angular Web Application from **Azure Cloud** after deployment.

In my chatbot project, need to fetch the user conversation data and send it to backend API from **Azure Bot Framework Composer**.

How to achieve this?, anyone help on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the conversation data using `${conversation}` scope and from dialog stack can access required information. To get last conversation data can use `${turn.Activity}`. For sending to backend API, create HTTP post method and pass the data in the body of your request.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details on your chatbot project, one reasonable approach to take is to use the Send HTTP Request action in the composer.

[image]

After you obtain the values from the conversation that you are looking for, (can be stored in conversation / dialog variables), you could then pass it onto an HTTP send request and deliver that to your backend API.

[image]

With this, you can send any payload to your backend API.

Comment: my actual question is how to fetch the user conversation data from bot?

Comment: Then you need to revisit the Bot Framework documentation on how to handle the conversation flow and data: 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/concept-memory

Comment: what visual tool is that?